# Linux mint doesn't show on bootmgr, directly boots to Windows

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, dualboot

I have Windows 10 and Linux installed on separate partitons, but my PC goes directly to Windows without displaying the OS menu. How do I fix this?

Comment: grub might be on other disk ; change boot order in bios

Comment: @Madhubala What should happen is the Windows boot manager should show Windows 10 and Linux, not the Linux boot manager. I formatted, then installed Linux then finally installed WIndows.

Comment: windows boot manager can't boot windows {since win can't read Linux partitions}; but there are ways to boot Linux using win boot manager - needs manual setup - but that is a different question

Comment: @Madhubala I got it to work but selecting Linux mint causes it to reboot, then reboot again and display the OS menu.